# Flutter 'Icons' takes too long to show list of icons

Tags: flutter, ubuntu

I am trying to put an icon in the bottom navigation bar
and I notice it may takes 2 minutes to show me the list of icons,
it takes much time loading like this.

[image]

**I use ubuntu operating system** but before I was using **windows 10** but I haven't experienced anything like that on windows

so anyone knows how to fix that?

Comment: Have you tried `flutter clean` or `invalidate and restart` your IDE?

Comment: I know flutter clean but what is invalidate?

Comment: It looks like you’re using an IntelliJ IDE. If so, there is an option to invalidate cache/restart in the file menu

Comment: I use android studio